# Give condition for "add an item" tree in odoo 8

Tags: python, xml, odoo-8

i have case about odoo, i was trying to give a condition for create in tree using attr. But, always not working. and here my code before i give a condition :

```
<tree string="Data" create="1" delete="1" edit="1" editable="bottom" >
```

i was trying add

```
attrs="{create:{'invisible': [('state', 'in', ('close', 'newer'))]}}"
```

But, that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in', ['close', 'newer'])]}}"`. This only works if it is a one2many field

Comment: I want the "add an item" to hide but by condition, not hide the value

Comment: Ah! OK, you should modify it on javascript then. If I have time later I will search the widget for you

Comment: But I am pretty sure that it is in the web module, the file `view_list.js`

Comment: Or you can just make it readonly in those cases. I updated my answer. But this only will work if it is a one2many field